# What should I do to use ELement class in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am using jGRASP version 2.0.0_03. (which uses jdk1.7.0_25) to write programs in java,
I am experimenting with XML with java for learning purposes...this is how I tried creating  an xml document in java:

```
private void writeFile()
  {
   dFact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   build = dFact.newDocumentBuilder();
   doc = build.newDocument();

   Element root = doc.createElement("outPutResult");
   doc.appendChild(root);

   for(Result r:resultList)
    {
     Element title = doc.createElement("Title");
     title.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(r.getTitle));
     root.appendChild(title);

     Element address = doc.createElement("Address");
     address.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(r.getAddress));
     root.appendChild(address);
    }


  }//End of Write function
```

I get errors as:

```
hw12.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    Document doc;
    ^
  symbol:   class Document
  location: class hw12
hw12.java:246: error: cannot find symbol
   Element root = doc.createElement("outPutResult");
   ^
  symbol:   class Element
  location: class hw12
```

what should I import to use  these classes?

Comment: Do you have your classpath configured? This error occurs when the java compiler can not find something, a data type, a call to a method ....

Comment: No, it is *not* a class path problem-- that would be a runtime error, not a compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those classes are in the package org.w3c.dom. You need import statements at the top of your source file like

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```

Et cetera.

Comment: do I need to add file in jdk? 

I tried it and got frustrated so using xmlWriterStream for now<

Comment: @Snedden27 no, the org.w3c.dom classes and interfaces are available by default, they're built in to the JRE class library.